# Delete last line in an open OutputStream

Tags: files-and-directories, streams

I have Mathematica code that creates a file (more precisely, I use [`OpenWrite`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OpenWrite.html) and create an [`OutputStream`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OutputStream.html) object) and I use [`WriteString`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WriteString.html) to write its contents. It turns out that sometimes I would like to delete the last line (or, optionally, the last few characters) I have written to the output file.

(I know it sounds like it is best to just not write them in the first place but I am hoping to find a fix in this way as this code is also needed in other places just the way it is.)

The only related question I found was [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87392/deleting-a-line-from-a-file), but there the function [`Put`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Put.html) is used to delete the whole previous file content. I would only like to delete the last line (or a certain number of characters in the end).

I would like to know if this is at all possible and if yes, how I could do that.

EDIT:

I was pointed to the usage of [`SetStreamPosition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetStreamPosition.html) to shift the place inside the stream where I continue writing.
However, it does not seem to work, since I get an error message. Here is a minimal example (in this case I am creating a fortran file but the problem does not depend on that) and the resulting message:

```
testFileStream = OpenWrite[ToFileName["/directory/" , "testStream" <> ".f90"]];

(* write test string into file*)
WriteString[testFileStream, "ABCDEF\n"];
(* checking the stream position ... as expected, this prints '7'*)
Print[StreamPosition[testFileStream]];
(*try to shift the stream position*)
SetStreamPosition[testFileStream, 5]
Close[testFileStream];
```

The message I get is:

> SetStreamPosition::openw: OutputStream[Name: testStream.f90
> Unique ID: 3] is open for output.

Could it be that `SetStreamPosition`, as seen in the example shown [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetStreamPosition.html), can only be used for [`InputStream`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputStream.html) objects?

If yes, is there another way for `OutputStream` objects?

Comment: You can get the stream position by "StreamPosition" and set a new stream position from where to write by "SetStreamPosition". Look it up in the help.

Comment: @DanielHuber Thank you very much for the suggestion! Unfortunately, it does not seem to work ... I edited my question and included an example to show the issue. Do you have an idea what the problem is?

Comment: You are right. It seems that SetStreamPosition only works for input, despite the help saying otherwise. Please report this to support@wolfram.com and let us know what they respond.